# Converting R console output into LaTeX table

Tags: r, latex

I was wondering if there is a package to convert the outputs obtained in R directly into LaTeX tables. For example, when running an ANOVA in R, the following output is obtained:

```
> summary(cry.aov)
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
ATPS               2 2.7951  1.3976   5.487 0.0442 *
Pretreatment       1 0.0070  0.0070   0.027 0.8740  
ATPS:Pretreatment  2 0.0421  0.0211   0.083 0.9217  
Residuals          6 1.5283  0.2547                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Could you get the coresponding LaTeX table code?

Comment: Try ‘[modelsummary](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/)’

Comment: have you looked at the CRAN package list?